# Two ParamArrays as Parameter in Function

Tags: .net, vb.net, paramarray

I was just trying to write a function like this:

```
Public Function myGetAttribute(ByVal xmlFileName As String, _
                                   ByVal ParamArray elementV() As String, _
                                   ByVal ParamArray attributesV() As String) As Collection
```

This is not working

> "End of parameter list expected. Cannot define parameters after a
>   paramarray parameter."

Why is it not possible to put two paramarrays as parameters and what is a workaround?

Comment: Because it's impossible to determine where the first array ends and starts the second

Comment: I see only one `ParamArray` in the signature you posted.

Comment: but the arrays have different names shouldnt it be possible to deterine where the first array ends and the second starts? svick: sorry, I edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be only one **ParramArray** and it has to be the last. It looks like you want pass two arrays as parameters to your sub and not an an unknown number of parameters.

```
Public Function myGetAttribute(ByVal xmlFileName As String, _
                                   ByVal elementV() As String, _
                                   ByVal attributesV() As String) As Collection
```

More here: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/538f81ec.aspx)